# Deriving a function from a small interval relationship

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I have the equation $${v(t+dt)=adt+f^{dt}v(t)}$$ where ${f}$ and ${a}$ are constants, that describes how a function, ${v(t)}$, changes over a small time interval ${dt}$. I'm aware that ${v(t+dt)-v(t)=dv}$, and if this equation were in the form ${v(t+dt)-v(t)=... dt}$, I could easily derive a ${v(t)}$ by finding $${v(T)=\int_0^T{...dt}}$$ I'm not sure solving for ${v(t+dt)-v(t)}$ is possible, so what's the best approach to finding ${v(t)}$?

Answer (score 1):

if we write:
$$f^{dt}=e^{dt\ln(f)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(dt\ln(f))^n}{n!}\approx1+dt\ln(f)$$
This can be said to be accurate since for small $dt$, higher powers of $dt$ will be insignificant, similar to how we might say $\sin(dt)=dt$. This gives us:
$$v(t+dt)=adt+\left[1+\ln(f)dt\right]v(t)$$

---

Another thought I have had is that if we assume $v$ to be continuous then we can say:
$$v(t+dt)=adt+f^{dt}v(t)$$
$$v(t-dt)=a(-dt)+f^{-dt}v(t)$$
adding together gives:
$$v(t+dt)+v(t-dt)=\left(f^{dt}+f^{-dt}\right)v(t)$$
$$\Rightarrow 2v(t)=(f^{dt}+f^{-dt})v(t)$$

This is not a full solution clearly, just some ideas :)

Comment: The first idea is interesting, I hadn't considered using serieses to solve this. Perhaps you could tell me how the relationship you derived is more useful that the one we started with? How would you derive v(t) from the relationship? As for the second approach, f^dt and f^(-dt) approach 1 for very small dt values, so I believe the final equation just says 2v(t)=2v(t). Also, I posted a fleshed-out solution if you want to check it out / poke holes in it.

Answer (score 0):

I took a bit of a strange approach to this one, and if anyone has a more elegant solution, feel free to post it.

First, I defined the problem as a limit, as $dt$ is an arbitrarily small time interval.
$$\lim_{dt\to 0}v(t+dt)=\lim_{dt\to 0}adt+f^{dt}v(t)$$
If we subtract $v(t)$ and divide by $dt$ on both sides, we get the formal definition of a derivative,
$$\lim_{dt\to 0}\frac{v(t+dt)-v(t)}{dt}=\lim_{dt\to 0}\frac{adt+f^{dt}v(t)-v(t)}{dt}$$
$$\frac{dv}{dt}=\lim_{dt\to 0}\frac{adt+f^{dt}v(t)-v(t)}{dt}$$
$$=a+v(t)\lim_{dt\to 0}\frac{f^{dt}-1}{dt}$$
$$=a+v(t)lnf$$
Now we have the differential equation,
$$\frac{dv}{dt}=a+vlnf$$
Which solves to,
$$v(t)=ke^{tlnF}-\frac{a}{lnf}$$
In my case, $v(0)$ was the only known value of $v(t)$, so I could derive $k$ by substituting $t=0$.
$$k=v(0)+\frac{a}{lnf}$$